# HP 625 with an ATI HD4200 crashes when watching videos on websites

Tags: fglrx

I have installed 11.10 on HP 625 (graphic card ATI/AMD Radeon HD4200), everything looks normal but if I see videos on websites (youtube, stream.cz, or similar), the whole Ubuntu crashes.

I have installed Catalyst 11.11 from AMD sites (according to this http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29) but Ubuntu still crashes.

Any idea how to solve this really annoying problem?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my HP 625 (yes I have the same computer). I know how to solve this problem (works for me).

- Remove catalyst from your computer. This solves crashing your PC.
- Install Adobe Flash player (and update the program if needed). It's free (i.e., costs nothing).
- Now you are able to see videos without crashing.

Have fun with your working hp 625!